# Google analytics creating accoung, insufficientPermissions, your project does not have access to this feature

Tags: symfony, google-api

I'm trying to create an account via google api from symfony using the **mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony**.
I got my token from jwt with the "**[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision**"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision**%22) scope.
But when I send the post request, I got this exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
                "message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."
    }
}
```

I already gave to my service account, the access to the main analytics account